# Logarithmic differentiation question

Tags: calculus

I came across this problem in my textbook:

[image]

I am a bit confused with it though because I thought the rule for this type of problem was:[image]

If the above rule is true, shouldn't the differentiation process look like this:
[image]

Where is that random $2x$ coming from in the numerator?

Comment: [Logarithmic differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation) is a technical term.

Comment: Cannot forget our friend `Chain Rule`. :) I think that should answer your ponders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**  The [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).  When we have composition of functions, such as $f(g(x))$, the derivative is $f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$.  (We multiply by the derivative of the inner function). The derivative of the "inside" in your case is the derivative of the function $x^2-1$, which is $2x$.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 3):

Let $u = x^2-1 $. Then  $y=\frac{1}{2} \log_5 u$.
So by the chain rule, we have

$$ \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} = \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}u}\cdot \frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}x}$$

You can then find $\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}u}$ by the rule you gave. Then make the necessary substitutions.
Hope this helps.